# Error appending SCRIPT HTML tag through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm managing a WordPress website using jQuery v3.6.0 + jQuery.migrate, it triggers a very weird error every time a SCRIPT code is appended to the page.

For example:

```
jQuery('body').append('<script>console.log("test")</script>');
```

The returned error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.head.appendChild(...) is undefined
```

Anyone has ever faced anything similar? Any hint on how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the string `<script>` into unrecognizable by compiler by splitting it to two words.

```js
jQuery('body').append('<sc' + 'ript>console.log("test")</scri' + 'pt>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The code runs, but the error is still thrown. Unfortunately this doesn't help me: I've got a dynamic variable containig random HTML code. How to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer solving the problem by NOT using jQuery.

```
$('.the_element')[0].innerHTML = contents;

let scripts = $('.the_element')[0].getElementsByTagName("script");
for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    eval(scripts[i].innerText);
}
```

*(honestly I still don't understand what jQuery might have on that customer website..!)*